# Can DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace() be used in after servererror trigger?

Tags: error-handling, oracle11g, triggers

We currently have a trigger setup on "after servererror on database" to log error information on an Oracle 11gR2 database.

Can I use the DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace() and/or DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack() functions to also log the error call stack information from within this trigger?